# iPhone: How to animate a destination board?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios4, animation, core-animation

do you know an approach to animate the digits of a destination board? I saw it already in some apps and now I need it for an own project.

[image]

Comment: One option is to use 4 or 5 images for the flip per number and use UIImageViews?

Answer (score 1):

Use `UIImageView` for numbers (there could be total 10 small images ) and flip them as per your requirement,